# Laravel, Handling validation errors in the Controller

Tags: php, laravel, rest, validation, request-validation

So i'm working on validating a form's inputs using the following code:

```
$request->validate([
    'title' => 'bail|required|max:255',
    'body' => 'required',
]);
```

So basically, there are two fields in the form, a title and a body and they have the above rules. Now if the validation fails I want to catch the error directly in the controller and before being redirected to the view so that I can send the error message as a response for the Post request. What would be the best way to do it?
I understand that errors are pushed to the session but that's for the view to deal with, but i want to deal with such errors in the controller itself.

Thanks

Comment: for this the best way to use custom validations of laravel where you can define your own error message

Comment: The solution shared in above comment is correct , You would have to use this class to make that code work use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have a look at the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation) you will see that you can handle the input validation in different ways.

In your case, the best solution is to [create the validator manually](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#manually-creating-validators) so you can set your own logic inside the controller.

> If you do not want to use the validate method on the request, you may create a validator instance manually using the Validator facade.

Here a little example:

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'title' => 'bail|required|max:255',
        'body' => 'required',
    ]);

    // Check validation failure
    if ($validator->fails()) {
       // [...]
    }

    // Check validation success
    if ($validator->passes()) {
       // [...]
    }

    // Retrieve errors message bag
    $errors = $validator->errors();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For someone who wants to know how to get validation errors after page redirection in the controller:

```
$errors = session()->get('errors');
if ($errors) {

    //Check and get the first error of the field "title"
    if ($errors->has('title')) {
         $titleError = $errors->first('title');
    }

    //Check and get the first error of the field "body"
    if ($errors->has('body')) {
         $bodyError = $errors->first('body');
    }
}
```

**$errors** will contain an instance of Illuminate/Contracts/Support/MessageBag

You can read more on the API here: https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Contracts/Support/MessageBag.html

**Note:** I have tested it in Laravel 8, it should work on Laravel 6+ if you get the MessageBag from the session